# FastAI fastbook - what does it do and why do I need to setup a book?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, fast-ai

I tried running on my google colab notebook:

```
!pip install -Uqq fastbook
import fastbook
```

as it is written in the FastAI book, chapter 2.
but nor the book or anywhere on google there is an explanation on what is this liberty at all.
amazingly, the [page](https://pypi.org/project/fastbook/) for it does not include any explanation on what fastbook does-  only about some course for deep learning.

so,

1. what does it do?

also, when I run:

```
fastbook.setup_book()
```

2. what does that do? in which way does it setup a book, and what kind of book is it?

ty.

Answer (score 2):

```html
fastbook.setup_book()
```

It is used setup when you are using google colab specifically and working with FastAI library. It helps to connect the colab notebook to google drive using an authentication token.

Answer (score 2):

1. `fastbook` relates to [the book/course](https://github.com/fastai/fastbook).
   The materials in the book use `fastai`, but also other libraries, e.g. `pandas` `graphviz` etc.
   `fastbook` has almost no library code itself, it mostly contains the dependencies one would need to follow the course. Plus, the book itself, of course.
   In other words: to run the code from the book/course, you will either need to `install fastai pandas graphviz ...`, or simply `install fastbook`.

   Watch the author himself talk about this: https://youtu.be/B6BQiIgiEks?t=441
2. During the course, you will download gigabytes of data: images/datasets/pretrained models. As well as more generally work with storage. You provide it from your GDrive.

Answer (score 1):

The code for fastbook is [here](https://github.com/fastai/course20/blob/master/fastbook/__init__.py) at the repo [fastai/course20](https://github.com/fastai/course20) instead of [fastai/fastbook](https://github.com/fastai/fastbook). It is a bit confusing.

Not much code in it. Most of them are for dependencies.